# django: flexible forms for restaurant menu?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm creating a menu system for restaurant, and need to be able to list menu items with flexible attributes that are sometimes selectable in django form from models (database). Since the number of items, and attributes aren't defined in advance, it needs to be flexible and the form needs to be able to render this.

Example use case:

```
1. Hawaiian Pizza
   * unselectable attributes: pineapple, ham (we are assuming you can't change this)
   * selectable attributes (all boolean True/False): spicy, extra cheese, extra meat, extra pineapple
   * prices: large - $9.99, extra large - $14.99
```

This would render as:

```
1. Hawaiian Pizza
Pineapple and Ham
[ ] spicy  [ ] extra cheese  [ ] extra meat  [ ] extra ham

$9.99 { button } 
$14.99 { button }
```

This enables me to place an order for

a) Hawaiian Pizza, with extra cheese, extra meat and make it spicy! Extra large at $14.99

or

b) Hawaiian Pizza making it spicy. Large at $9.99

In an ideal situation, I would even add a price to the "extra attributes".

**Anyone have any idea how I can get flexible attributes? ... or suggestions for how to achieve this?**

This seems like Drupal would have been ideal, with it's flexible attribute system.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use additional model to connect options with an item, something like:

```
class Option(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(...) # group name for radios, option name for checks
    required = models.BooleanField() # is radio?

class ItemOptions(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option)
    value = models.CharField(...) # option value
    price = models.DecimalField() # if applied
```

Then you'll just need to display a checkbox for each optional field, then radiobutton for each required one (with the same `name` in few radios for one option). Then put all order data in `PickleField` or `JSONField` or just add another model to store those relations.